# Concatenating to a URL from an input Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, concatenation

I am making a web application in BOOTSTRAP/Javascript that retrieves high scores from a JSON and then checks for available quests.

Currently this is how I am set up in my javascript file

```
var baseURL = 'https://www.tip.it/runescape/json/hiscore_user?rsn=&old_stats=1';
var updatedURL =;
var requestURL = updatedURL;
var request = new XMLHttpRequest()

request.open('GET', requestURL);
request.responseType = 'json';
request.send();
request.onload = function() {
  var userStats = request.response;
}


function URLupdater() {
}
```

What I am trying to do is concatenate information from a input form on my html page,

```
        <div id="Userinput" class="col-md-2">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"> <img src="/img/admincrown.gif~c200.gif" class="img-rounded" width="20" height="20"> </span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Runescape Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="submitbutton" class="col-md-1"><button id="retrievestats" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Get Stats</button></div>
```

into the baseURL above after ?rsn=

I am currently attempting to make a function that reads the input on button click, then switches the url to the new one with the username in it and then continuing from there to retrieve the JSON Data. Am I thinking about this the right way or am I off track.

Answer (score 0):

You mean what you are trying to achieve is as such? :

```
var baseURL = 'https://www.tip.it/runescape/json/hiscore_user?rsn=&old_stats=1&concatenatedData=1234';
```

If so, I don't see any issues with it. You seem okay to proceed.

Comment: Yes precisely except the concatenated data will be a username this placed precisely after (rsn=), and only the username. Will this prove to be more difficult?

Comment: Will not really, just prepend the string after the occurrence of "rsn="

Answer (score 0):

## Not future-proof

Assuming you **only** want to append a username to the URL, and don't need to manipulate it in any other way, you can perhaps do it like this:

```
function getUserData( user_name ) {
    var requestURL = "https://www.tip.it/runescape/json/hiscore_user?old_stats=1&rsn=",
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open( "GET", requestURL + encodeURIComponent( user_name ) );
    // various sanitizations should be employed on the backend when dealing with user input
    request.responseType = "json";
    request.setRequestHeader( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" );
    request.addEventListener( "readystatechange", function() {
        if ( request.readyState == 4 ) {
            if ( request.status == 200 ) {
                var user_stats = request.responseText;
                // process response
            } else {
                // handle errors
            }
        }
    }, false );
    request.send();
}

window.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    document.getElementById( "retrievestats" ).addEventListener( "click", function() {
        var user_input = document.querySelector( "#Userinput input[name=user_name]" ),
            user_name;
        if ( user_input ) {
            user_name = user_input.value;
            if ( user_name ) {
                getUserData( user_name );
            }
        }
    }, false );
}, false );
```

There are of course many other factors in reality and this is just *a* bunch of code, not *the* bunch of code.

**HTML**

Instead of wrapping your *form* in a `<div>`, you could consider using a [`<form>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms). It isn't vital, but makes sense and can be as simple as altering a few tags (and CSS).

```
<form id="Userinput" class="col-md-2">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"> <img src="/img/admincrown.gif~c200.gif" class="img-rounded" width="20" height="20"> </span>
        <input name="user_name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Runescape Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
    </div>
    <div id="submitbutton" class="col-md-1">
        <input id="retrievestats" type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Get Stats">
    </div>
</form>
```

**Summary**

As the code you provided and the limited explanation for its existence is obviously only a small part of a greater whole, there are too many variables to cover in one answer. As far as tacking a username onto a "GET" URL goes, this'll work. The rest - I can't say.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#retrievestats').click(function() {
        var enteredname = document.getElementById('Userinputform').value.toLowerCase();
        var RSname = enteredname;
        alert(RSname);
    });
});` This is what I used to get the username into a variable and it seems to work. I also implemented what you provided and it doesn't seem to break anything yet but I am going to try accessing the user_stats now and see if it actuallly worked.